# How Unity make GameObject instance destroyed while it is referenced?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, GameObject can be destroyed.

Here's the scenario:

1. **Instantiate GameObjectA and GameObjectB**
2. **Add a script to GameObjectA** (this script can hold reference of another GameObject)
3. **Script in GameObjectA find and hold the reference of GameObjectB**.

From here everything is happy. We can do anything with GameObjectB.

4. **Destroy GameObjectB** using GameObject.Destroy

**Here** when we access GameObjectB from GameObjectA's script it will be null.

You can't access any methods, fields and properties because it have been destroyed.

---

**Problem is how they can do that?**

If you think about it carefully.

In pure C# object GC will not collect if someone retain the reference of that instance.

I know Unity have their wrapper layers to those object.

But I wonder how it's work? And how to implement it in C#?

Comment: What do you mean by referenced? 
You can do :
GameObjectB = GameObjectA;
And it will take all properties of it.

Comment: @GhAyoub Sorry for make you misunderstand. I've edited the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a subtlety here. In your example, if you check **GameObject B** it will *return equals* to null. But that's because Unity have overridden the equality operator of `UnityEngine.Object`. If you actually try to access any of the `GameObject`'s properties or methods, you won't get a `NullReferenceException`; you'll get an exception from Unity saying that the object has been destroyed.

In other words, it still exists from the point of view of .NET/Mono's memory management. So to answer your question, 'how to implement it in C#,' the trick is the equality override. But even Unity themselves have had second thoughts about that design choice, so don't try it at home.

Comment: How about those method, properties? How they know it have been destroyed since we hand write that method ourself.

Comment: Can you give an example where accessing methods or properties in your own code gives an error?